# push array key and value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to push array into existing session array. I would like to use get[id] and I want to be able stack all the arrays added rather than delete them when a new array is pushed.

Bellow is my code and I am not getting the value, instead I get this error --- Array to string conversion. Thanks in advance.

```
**CODE
  <?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['animals']))
{
$_SESSION['animals']=array();

}


// push array 
array_push($_SESSION['animals'],  array ( 'id' => "".$_GET['id'].""));

 foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
 {   

    // and print out the values

    echo $key; 
    echo $value;
    }
?>
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: echo $value;   is the error

Comment: You can run the code easily using the code I posted. there are no additional pages need for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, this is what $_SESSION looks like:

```
array (size=1)
  'animals' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

In your code :

```
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
```

`key` will contain `0` and `value` will contain `array('id' => 'test')`. Since `value` is an array, you cannot echo it like this.

If you want to echo all the characteristics of each animal, this code will work :

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['animals']))
{
    $_SESSION['animals'] = array();
}

// push array 
array_push($_SESSION['animals'],  array ( 'id' => "".$_GET['id'].""));

// We go through each animal
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$animal)
{   
    echo 'Animal n°'.$key; 
    // Inside each animal, go through each attibute
    foreach ($animal as $attribute => $value)
    {
        echo $attribute;
        echo $value;

    }
}
```

Comment: YES! thanks Heru-Luin-- it works. Just one question, why is the key still starting from 0? i thought it will be replaced by the id?

Comment: Because the 'id' => 1 has a key of id and a value of 1

Comment: Because with array_push, you append an array to an array.
If you want to remove the [0], use `$_SESSION['animals']['id'] = $_GET['id']."";` instead of the `array_push`.
Then, your original code will work.